# Прошу указать мне на ошибки в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, запятые

А, потом уже о пенсии думайте.

Comment: У вас ошибка - в заголовке.

Comment: В каком заголовке?

Comment: В том, который вам исправил @АлександрСтрелец.

Comment: Я не про заголовок. После А надо ставить запятую или нет?

Answer (score 1):

*После А надо ставить запятую или нет?*

**4.** (в начале вопросит. и восклиц. предл., в начале реплики или при внезапном переходе от одной мысли, темы к другой; обычно со словами: как, какой, сколько и т. п.). Употребляется для усиления выразительности. *А знаешь, мама, о чём я думаю? А что говорят учёные? А как будет весело! А сколько таких поэтов?! Что с вами? — А ничего, слушаю.*

Думаю, что запятая после "А" не нужна:
**А потом уже о пенсии думайте.**

> Чем больше говорили они и спорили, тем меньше  понимали  они  друг
> друга. **А потом уже** они молчали, полные ненависти и презрения друг к другу (В. Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба).

― Так надо было по роли. **А потом уже** некогда было переодеваться. Не успел. ― Артисты… ― только и сказал начальник. [Василий Шукшин. Калина красная (1973)]

> — А теперь еще слинял. Ну ничего, я его быстренько... **А потом уже** женимся как следует (В. Ремизов. Воля вольная).

[**А**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B0), *союз, частица, междометие*

Comment: Спасибо большое